# Структура регистров для хранения хранения оборудования с разделением по зданиям и кабинетам

Tags: 1с

Если стоит задача учёта объектов(оборудования, мебели и прочего)  с вложенностью: здание, кабинет. Какую структуру регистров лучше использовать. Если сделать один регистр накопления с измерениями: здание, помещение, оборудование. Будет ли это грамотным решением? Или лучше использовать другие/несколько регистров?

Comment: Конечно лучше все хранить в одном месте !

Answer (score 0):

Здания, кабинеты - в иерархический справочник(или подчиненный), в регистре, я так понимаю, будет считаться количество. Ну и оборудование(мебель, прочее) тоже справочник. Думаю взлетит.